# How to match multiple different patterns with exactly one occurrence in any order?

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm fine-tuning the creation of a complex regex. I'm nearly there, but I think I'm missing something.

I would like to test the validity of a string that is to be used as a formatting pattern, such that the result of the test is true or false and the entire expression is captured fully within the regex.

> A. The pattern MUST contain four different placeholder identifiers exactly once.
>
> B. The pattern MAY contain the four placeholder identifiers in any order.
>
> C. The pattern MUST NOT nest placeholders.
>
> D. The placeholder identifiers SHOULD be matched with case sensitivity.
>
> E. The placeholder identifiers SHOULD take the form `{\w{2,4}}`.
>
> F. The pattern SHOULD ignore patterns in the placeholder that are similar in form to the placeholder identifiers.

For this question, the placeholder identifiers (including their delimiters) are:

- `{Desc}`
- `{Rg}`\
- `{RqID}`
- `{RT}`

Here is a set of test patterns and the expected results:

1. `$testPattern -cmatch '{RqID}{Rg}{Desc}{RT}'` ⇒ `$true`
2. `$testPattern -cmatch '{Desc}-{RqID}-{RT}-{Rg}'` ⇒ `$true`
3. `$testPattern -cmatch '#{RqID}: {Desc} [{Rg}-{RT}]'` ⇒ `$true`
4. `$testPattern -cmatch '{Desc}-{RqId}-{RT}-{Rg}'` ⇒ `$false` (fails D on case matching)
5. `$testPattern -cmatch '{Desc}-{Rq}-{RT}-{Rg}'` ⇒ `$false` (fails A, badly named placeholder)
6. `$testPattern -cmatch '{RqID}{RT}{Rg}{Desc}{RT}'` ⇒ `$false` (fails A, duplicate placeholder)
7. `$testPattern -cmatch '{RqID}, {Desc, {Rg}}, {RT}'` ⇒ `$false` (fails C, nesting)

I think that's probably adequate to show how I want this to work.

### What I tried:

I tried a combination of negative lookbehind and positive lookahead assertions combined with a backreference.

The closest I can get is this:

```
(?<!{\1}.*){(Desc|Rg|RqID|RT)}(?!.*{\1})
```

And to check that `$Matches.Count -eq 4`. This seems to work... but ...

Ideally, I would like to express the entire condition with the regex such that my test would simply yield `$true`, rather than checking how many matches I found.

I feel like I'm either missing something about lookaround assertions or backreference that would make this produce the result I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your description you should be able to get a pass/fail result with this regex:

```
^(?=.*\{RqID})(?=.*\{Rg})(?=.*\{Desc})(?=.*\{RT})(?!.*(\{(Desc|Rg|RqID|RT)}).*\1)
```

It includes positive lookaheads for each of the four placeholders, and a negative lookahead to ensure that none of the placeholders are repeated.

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/1wOIrY/1)

That regex will simply yield a match/no-match result. If you also want to capture the expression with the regex, add `.*$` to the end of it:

```
^(?=.*\{RqID})(?=.*\{Rg})(?=.*\{Desc})(?=.*\{RT})(?!.*(\{(Desc|Rg|RqID|RT)}).*\1).*$
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/1wOIrY/2)

Comment: You have to add `.*$` at the end to match the whole input as requested by the questioner. Besides that, good answer!

Comment: @Thomas I don't believe that is necessary; the lookaheads will guarantee all of OPs 6 requirements. Note that the regex of itself doesn't actually match any characters at all, it is just a series of zero-width assertions. So just adding `$` will break it; it would need to be `.*$`, which is redundant as it doesn't add any further constraints to the regex.

Comment: `.*$` is what I requested ;-) Questioner needs "result of the test is true or false and the entire expression is captured fully within the regex." The lookarounds will say "true" or "false", but capture nothing. To capture the whole expression `.*$` is mandatory imo.

Comment: @Thomas sorry - I thought when I looked at your comment it just said `$`. Anyway, I didn't add that because I interpreted "Ideally, I would like to express the entire condition with the regex such that my test would simply yield $true" as just desiring a regex which would yield a match/nomatch result. I've added a note to the answer to clarify.

Comment: For both @Nick and @Thomas: my apology for sloppy wording around "captures". I don't actually need to capture the matched value. I meant that I didn't want to add any conversion to the result of the regex evaluation that would yield true/false (like my test for `$Matches.Count -eq 4` workaround). The `.*$` is, however, frosting on the cake -- it makes my intention that much clearer (at the cost of wasted cycles and that's okay by me), so I'm glad you added it.

Comment: @AlanMcBee-MSFT I think the `.*$` will be minimal extra cycles relative to processing the 5 lookaheads so if it's useful you should definitely add it.